# How to export raster file with a known color ramp?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, color-ramp

I have a single band raster file( that it is Grayscale) and I changed its symbology to unique value with a Known color ramp.

How can I save this raster file with its color ramp (to .tiff) so that it is displayed with that color ramp outside of ArcMap (in any picture viewer software)?

Comment: what do you mean by "outside of arcmap" ? Another GIS software or simply a "picture" viewer ?

Comment: My mean is a picture viewer software.

Answer (score 1):

For viewing in a picture viewer software, which often do not read colormaps properly, the most robust method is to export an rgb file (in 3*8bits).

Simply go to file >  Export map and this will create an RGB file in the format that you need. In layout view, you can make a map layout. In data view, the current display extent will be exported.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to `right-click the raster layer with the symbology in the table of content -> Data -> Export data`

[image]

Under `Output Raster` check both `Use Rendered` and `Force RGB`

[image]

You can open the output raster file (tif format) in any picture editing/viewing software such as Photoshop, GIMP, or any other software.